# Премодерация коментариев на сайте (телефон и email)

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день!

Возникла такая проблема, нужно определять в тексте коментария телефон и email и если они есть заменять их на * (звезды), но:
люди по разному ухитряются писать телефоны и email:
+7 999 876 87 89
+7 999-876-87-89
89998768789
и так далее, таже эпопея с email.

Есть ли какие нибудь мысли?

Comment: @BlackWidow,  `[^@\s]@[^@\s]\.\w{2,}` для имейлов, `[\d\+][\d\s\-]{6,}` для телефонов. Если нужна стопроцентная защита, то проще реализовать наивный анализатор, который смотрит, сколько в последних словах цифр и банит их, если их слишком много.

Comment: может правильно будет добавить поле для телефона?

Comment: нет, нужно именно не дать комментатору опубликовать свой телефон и email. А то ручки у них так и тянутся телефон и мыло дать другому участнику беседы

Comment: Регулярные выражения тут могут и не покатить, потому что почту многие могут писать как mail(at)mail.ru или или mail (собака) mail.ru или mail собака mail.ru, в номерах телефонов заменять 4 на Ч, ну и т.д.

Comment: @Heidel, это намеренное желание участника обмануть машину, и от него не спастись вообще в принципе.

Comment: @BlackWidow, на мой взгляд проще будет отловить момент передачи контактных данных не по наличию телефона или email, а по просьбе связаться. Используйте определенные слова и словосочетания как маркеры. Добавьте им вес и если он превышает какое-то пороговое значение - помечайте комментарий как вам нужно и не публикуйте